# I am trying to save inputs using combo boxes and a date time picker to a ms access database and it says : Data type mismatch in criteria Expression

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ZwaneZP01\source\repos\HenleyFaultsSystemSbu\Faults.accdb;";
            con.Open();

            using (var com = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Faults ([Date],[Job],[Area],[ReportedBy],[ReportedTo],[Equipment],[Workshop]," +
                    "[SerialNo],[Delay],[TimeSpent],[FANo],[Category],[Fault],[Action],[Status]) " +
                    "VALUES (@Date,@Job,@Area,@ReportedBy,@ReportedTo,@Workshop,@Equipment,@Fault,@Action,@Delay,@TimeSpent,@Status,@SerialNo,@FANo,@Category)";

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", comboBox1.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Area", AreacomboBox2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportedBy", NameCodeReportedBy.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportedTo", ReportedToBox.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Workshop", WorkshopBox.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Equipment", EquipmentBox.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fault", textBox2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", textBox3.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delay", DelayBox.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeSpent", TimeBox.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", checkBox1.Checked);

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNo", textBox4.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FANo", textBox5.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", CategoryComboBox.Text);



                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not saved: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

//So this is not saving to the database

I tried changing the date format as I thought its probably the date but that has not helped either

I expect it to save to the data but I am getting an error about criteria mismatch

Comment: What exactly the exception message says?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to fix is removing all those AddWithValue and replacing them with

```
com.Parameters.Add("@Date", OleDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.DateTime;
```

and so on...
This is important because AddWithValue is not able to pass a parameter of type DateTime as expected by your database table if you give it a string of text. You should alwasy be 
precise when providing parameters to your underlying database (MS-Access or not)

But then there is another problem. The OleDb library is not able to recognize the parameters by their names and assign the value to the correct place in your sql. 
OleDb pass the parameters values looking at their position in the collection so the parameter @Workshop is assigned to the Equipment field and viceversa the parameter @Equipment is assigned to the Workshop field.
You should arrange your parameter list following the exact order in which the parameter placeholders appears in the sql text and, of course, verify that every parameter placeholder matches the corresponding field to update